# query string?

Tags: html, query-string

I have some doubts.
 What is querystrng? how we can use it? what are the advantages? what are the parameters using for querystring?

Comment: In your language, what do _you_ call the part of a URL that comes after the "?"

Comment: You should write something concrete...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

query string is one of the state management techniques in .net. You can pass parameters from one page to another page like Response.Redirect("test.aspx?id=101"); and you can access those values in recieving page.

here it is test.apsx. in test.aspx page load you can retieve those values by

```
string id = Request.QueryString["id"].ToString();
```

Comment: You don't need the ToString() here, it already is a string.

Comment: It's also not a .NET state management technique - it's a standard part of URLs since way before .NET.

Answer (score 2):

The [Query string](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string) entry says:

> In World Wide Web, a query string is the part of a Uniform Resource Locator (URL) that contains data to be passed to web applications such as CGI programs.

and

> A typical URL containing a query string is as follows:
>
> `http://server/path/program?query_string`
>
> When a server receives a request for such a page, it runs a program (if configured to do so), passing the query_string unchanged to the program. The question mark is used as a separator and is not part of the query string.

Answer (score 0):

The original use case for a query string was the kind of page that had a "Search:" label next to a text box, with "Submit" and "Reset" buttons under it. You'd fill in the text box and click "Submit" and it would issue a "GET" request, perhaps to the same URL, where it would do a search based on the query you typed in.

The stuff you typed into the text box would be placed into the query string.

Answer (score -1):

You should rewrite and clean the URLs of your website. User-friendly URLs do not contain query strings. clean URLs allow Search Engines to read the keywords in the URL and put emphasis.

Usability is the other reason for designing a clean URL structure on your website: clean URLs are much easier to remember for your visitors. Visitors will find hard to remember a URL using strange parameters, not to mention that they would be discouraged by the idea of typing the entire URL.

Comment: I doubt anyone will be typing in the URL to this question ever.